# ADO Recordset Source as Command - CommandTimeout ignored

Tags: vb6, ado

I'm trying to update a VB6 legacy app which is dealing with a very large database.  I need to open a recordset for possible update which has 250K records.  No sweat for SQL Server.  All you have to do set the CommandTimeout property.

In this case, I cannot use the command.Execute method, because that will not return an updatable recordaet.  So, I create a command object, set it's properties, and supply that to a Recordset.Open method.  This fails with an "Object was Open" error, long before the timeout period -- meaning the command.CommandTimeout was ignored.  Connection string is standard.

```
                 Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
                '...connection opened (not shown)
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
                Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
                cmd.ActiveConnection = con
                cmd.CommandTimeout = 600
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM BIGTABLE"

                cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

                With rsBigTable
                    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
                    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
                    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
                   .Open cmd  'This give me the error above

                End With
              '  Set rsBigTable= cmd.Execute
               This opens the recordset, but not with parameters I need, such as locktype
```

Comment: Is it the connection or the command that is closing? That has a CommandTimeout as well - and I think it defaults to 30 or 60 seconds

Comment: And the connection has a ConnectionTimeout that can be set as well

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no such thing as a client-side keyset recordset.  Client-side recordsets are always static, and your `adUseClient` setting will override your `adOpenKeyset` setting (without telling you) and set it to `adStatic`.  So, you don't have an updatable recordset there, although it might seem that you do.  (Debug your code and check the CursorType property before and after executing `.CursorLocation = adUseClient` and you will see this for yourself.  I had to, 20 years ago, before I was convinced.)  Hopefully this will save you some further headaches down the line.

If you want a batch-updatable, client-side recordset, you need to set `LockType` to `adLockBatchOptimistic`, and research how to batch post changes ([here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675835(v=vs.85).aspx) a code example from the Microsoft doc).  `adLockOptimistic` is ignored on a static recordset, since the recordset isn't updatable.  Otherwise, the only updatable recordsets in ADO are server-side.

As for your problem with the recordset already being open, I'm sorry, but I'm skeptical of your conclusion that the CommandTimeout is being ignored.  It's more likely that you've opened the recordset already somehow.  Of course, I'm basing that on what I can see here, and you haven't shown us the code through the lifetime of your recordset.

In any case, you'll need to clean up these other things.  And one more thing, here:

```
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
```

Take the `New` out of the `Dim` statement.  VB6 doesn't work like .Net and actually instantiate the object on the `Dim` line (as a side point, if it did, your second line would be redundant).  Rather, it checks for an instance of the object every time you reference it, and instantiates one if it can't find it.  This, obviously, creates unnecessary overhead.  So declare the object variable on one line, and instantiate it on another, as you have it here.